# enum type for BlueSteel Avro encoding/decoding library for Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need the sample code base to use BlueSteel Avro encoding swift library for enum type.

I have tried below code base :

```
import BlueSteel
struct EnumType {
    var enumType = enumTypes.one
}

extension EnumType: AvroValueConvertible {
    func toAvro() -> AvroValue {
        return AvroValue.AvroRecordValue(["enumType": AvroValue.AvroEnumValue(self.enumType.rawValue, "enumType")])
    }
}

enum enumTypes: Int {
    case one, two, three, four, five
}
```

Comment: **Tried Below code base :** _End result is coming as **AvroInvalidValue**_      `func testBlueSteel() {
  let jSchema = "{\"name\": \"match\", \"type\": {\"type\": \"enum\", \"name\": \"HandshakeMatch\", \"symbols\": [\"BOTH\", \"CLIENT\", \"NONE\"]}}"
  let schema = Schema(jSchema)
  let value = AvroValue.AvroEnumValue(1, "CLIENT")
  
  if let serialize = value.encode(schema) {
   print(serialize)
   
   let avroValue = AvroValue(schema: schema, withBytes: serialize)
   print("Result : \(avroValue)")
  }
  }`

Comment: Result is always coming as : Result : AvroInvalidValue